# TIdHTTP sends HTTPS request as HTTP over proxy

Tags: delphi, fiddler, indy, delphi-xe8, idhttp

I've got an issue with implementing SSL Certificate Pinning with `TIdHTTP`.

So, here are the steps:

1. Drop TIdHTTP, TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL and TIdCompressorZLib on the form.
2. Assign TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL and TIdCompressorZLib to IOHandler and Compressor properties of TIdHTTP.
3. Setup TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL:

   ```
   Port = 0
   DefaultPort = 0
   SSLOptions.Method = sslvTLSv1_2
   SSLOptions.SSLVersions = [sslvTLSv1_2]
   SSLOptions.Mode = sslmClient
   SSLOptions.VerifyMode = [sslvrfPeer]
   SSLOptions.VerifyDepth = 0
   OnVerifyPeer = SSLIOHandlerVerifyPeer
   ```
4. Code for SSLIOHandlerVerifyPeer:

   ```
   function TForm2.SSLIOHandlerVerifyPeer(Certificate: TIdX509; AOk: Boolean; ADepth, AError: Integer): Boolean;
   const
     LCGoogleCert = '98:1D:34:C4:F8:4A:F2:B7:C7:AB:77:AD:51:1C:51:4C:AD:76:ED:0D:0E:FA:C9:63:68:AF:28:69:94:60:BF:7A';
   begin
     Result := Certificate.Fingerprints.SHA256AsString.Equals(LCGoogleCert);
   end;
   ```
5. Drop a button on a form:

   ```
   procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
   const
     LCGoogleURL = 'https://www.google.com/';
   var
     s: UnicodeString;
   begin
     s := HTTPSender.Get(LCGoogleURL);
   end;
   ```
6. Install [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler)
7. In Fiddler: Tools - Options - check "Capture HTTPS Connects" and uncheck "Decrypt HTTPS traffic". Generate and install certificate to system.
8. Set Fiddler's proxy address and port to TIdHTTP.
9. Run program and click the button. First click - you get the exception about the incorrect certificate. But if you click the second time - you won't get any exceptions, but you'll get the full response and you'll see the unencrypted traffic in Fiddler as if you sent the request via HTTP and not HTTPS.

You can see the result of the first and the second request on the picture below. So is this a bug in Indy component, or I'm trying to implement SSL Pinning incorrectly?

[image: Fiddler]

Comment: No. Decrypt is switched off (see 7). If Fiddler decrypts HTTPS traffic it shows "HTTPS" in the Protocol colums. Here the first line is from the failed request and the second is from the second request which should fail too but was sent via HTTP instead of HTTPS. These steps can be reproduced on the newest version of Indy too. Here's the https decrypted request: https://imgur.com/a/kDz2F75

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the first call to `TIdHTTP.Get()`, the `OnVerifyPeer` event sees Fiddler's SSL/TLS certificate instead of Google's, so it rejects the certificate, and the underlying socket connection ends up being closed.

However, there is unread data left behind in the IOHandler's `InputBuffer` (approx 162 bytes of encrypted data).  *By design*, the `TIdIOHandlerStack.Connected()` method returns True as long as there is unread data available to satisfy read operations, even if there is no physical socket connection.

So, what ends up happening during the second call to `TIdHTTP.Get()` is the following:

- `TIdHTTP` knows it is communicating over HTTPS through a proxy, and that it is making a new HTTP request to the same Google server through the same proxy as the previous call to `TIdHTTP.Get()`.  So `TIdHTTP` checks `Connected()` to see if it is still connected to the proxy, and sees that `Connected()` is initially True, so it makes the decision to skip a new `CONNECT` request and proceed as if it is sending a new HTTP request over an existing proxy connection.
- However, since the underlying socket was disconnected, `TIdHTTP` has to make a new socket connection to Fiddler.  While preparing for the new HTTP request, the `InputBuffer` gets cleared.  `Connected()` is checked again, and is now False, so `TIdHTTP` makes a new socket connection to Fiddler.  That new socket connection is initially unencrypted (the IOHandler's `PassThrough` is set to True) so a subsequent `CONNECT` would not be encrypted (but this section of code does not know that `TIdHTTP` had already decided to skip `CONNECT`).
- `TIdHTTP` proceeds to send the `GET` request to Fiddler, unencrypted.
- Fiddler caches its TLS tunnels for a period of time, and so it reuses the existing tunnel to Google, thus forwarding the unencrypted `GET` as-is to Google over a TLS connection, and then forwards the response unencrypted back to `TIdHTTP`.

So, ultimately, there are three issues at play here (I have opened a [ticket in Indy's issue tracker](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/212)):

- `TIdHTTP` is not clearing the `InputBuffer` when a failure occurs that requires the underlying socket to be closed.  A simply fix for this is to make the `TIdCustomHTTP.ConnectToHost()` method clear the `InputBuffer` of any existing data before doing anything else.  That way, it sees the connection is really gone before deciding what to do about `CONNECT`.  I have now checked in this fix to Indy's SVN repository, and tested that it works in your scenario.
- `TIdHTTP` is making the decision to send or skip `CONNECT` too soon, before it knows what it is doing with the underlying socket.  This will require some re-writing of `TIdHTTP`'s internal logic, so it will be deferred to a later version of Indy.
- Fiddler is forwarding unencrypted data back and forth over a previously encrypted tunnel.  Nothing can be done about that in `TIdHTTP`.